# Knockout.js equivalent of AngularJS events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

In AngularJS when you have nested scopes (e.g. two nested directives) you can easily communicate between them with `scope.$broadcast()` and `scope.$emit()`. Is there an easy way to communicate like this between nested components (custom elements) in Knockout.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. No such thing in KnockoutJS.

If you need it to do some kind of event / pub-sub thing you'd need to include such a library for your specific purpose, e.g. [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) or another event system (I guess you *could* mimick one or make a poor-man's version with vanilla js and Knockout too).

If you think you need it because your view isn't getting updated when you change your view models, then you should probably be replacing plain Javascript members of your view models with actual observables. Contrary to Angular (which uses digest cycles), KnockoutJS has dependency tracking that will notify every part of your "scope" that is dependent on a particular other part.